# Facebook friends select dialog in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK on iOS 8 and I would like to use the friend picker dialog but I can't find it. There seems to be no reference to it on the Facebook Developers portal.

Do I have to write my own friend picker dialog?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Friend picker dialog is no more available Facebook SDK v4.1.0,

Instead, you have to call Graph API to fetch the friend list:-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/invitable_friends
```

For more info see [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector#step1)

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook v4 changelog, all FB*ViewController were deprecated and we should build our own table view controller to show friends list.

You have to use Graph API to fetch friends.

> The SDK has two classes to work with the Graph API: FBSDKGraphRequest and FBSDKGraphRequestConnection

Thanks